# Select everything between two timestamps in a log file

Tags: regular-expression

```shell
awk '/10:..:/, /13:..:/' server.log > /tmp/awktmp
```

I tried this command as someone gave me. It worked for me to find logs between 10:00 AM to 13:00 PM but I don't understand it fully.

Please tell me an elegant solution if you've one. Remember the remote servers are minimal and don't have advanced utilities.

What I don't understand here is `'/10:..:/, /13:..:/'`

- I understand `10:..` means `10` and `:` and match exactly 2 digits.
- But what does another `:` mean?

I suppose the forwardslashes are for putting regular expression like we do in JavaScript regex. I'm not 100% sure about that.

**Update 1:**

Time is in second column, in format `HH:MM:SS`

**Update 2:**

```shell
sed -n -e '/8:..:../,/9:..:../p' application.log > /tmp/sedtmp
```

I tried this but this is also showing logs from `07:57:47`.

**Update 3**

The logs don't always contain the timestamp in each row.
Some rows don't contain any timestamp at all. How'd you overcome that issue? I stupidly used awk and I missed all the rows which didn't have time value in them. Is there a way to avoid this issue?

Like this is what I mean.

```
2023-08-07 09:20:35 0123456789 INFO  CustomerLogoutResource:95 - Entering logout api.
2023-08-07 09:20:35 0123456789 ERROR AppExceptionMapper:87 - Exception has been thrown by container
2023-08-07 09:20:35 0123456789 ERROR AppExceptionMapper:555 - Unchecked Exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at NullPointerExceptionExample.printLength(NullPointerExceptionExample.java:3)
    at NullPointerExceptionExample.main(NullPointerExceptionExample.java:8)
```

Comment: Can you check the logs carefully? Three possible causes. (a) The lines with 07:57:47 may have something else in the same line that **does** match (remember awk knows about columns, but sed examines the whole line). (b) The logged messages may not be in precise time order (they may be buffered, or come from systems with clock drift), so there may be a previous line that *did* have 08:??:??. (c) A line from the previous day for 18:??:?? may have triggered the range, because you **still** omit the leading zero on the hour. Cannot you just cut columns 1 and 2 and post those to PasteBin ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That kind of approach fails to find the lines for `11:00` to `13:00` if there are no log inbetween 10:00 and 11:00 and would report all lines after `14:00` if there was no log in between 13:00 and 14:00 (and there was at least one between 10 and 11).

Best for this kind of thing it to do lexical comparison of the the time against the boundaries.

For instance, if the time is in the third field:

```bash
awk '$3 >= "10:00:00" && $3 < "13:00:00"'
```

If you don't know where in the line the time is, you could do:

```bash
perl -lne 'print if /\b\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\b/ &&
                      $& ge "10:00:00" &&
                      $& lt "13:00:00"'
```

Or:

```bash
LC_ALL=C awk 'match($0, /[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/) && \
                (t = substr($0, RSTART, 8)) >= "10:00:00" && \
                t < "13:00:00"'
```

Those report the lines that have a timestamp in the range. If you have lines without timestamps in between lines with timestamps and you want them reported, you can use the `beginning-condition, end-condition {action}` approach like in your question but again use comparison instead of regex match, or do the state switching by hand so as to keep excluding the upper boundary:

```bash
LC_ALL=C awk -v beg=10:00:00 -v end=13:00:00 '
  match($0, /[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/) {
    t = substr($0, RSTART, 8)
    if (t >= end) selected = 0
    else if (t >= beg) selected = 1
  }
  selected'
```

Comment: With a POSIX awk for RE intervals you could make `[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]` slightly briefer as `[0-2][0-9](:[0-5][0-9]){2}` but obviously no big deal either way. FWIW I find tests for a value inside a range slightly clearer written as `'"10:00:00" <= $3 && $3 < "13:00:00"'` rather than `'$3 >= "10:00:00" && $3 < "13:00:00"'` so the code mimics and highlights the functionality that `$3` is between the other values and so you don't even have to think about what it means when you see it but again nbd.

Comment: @Stephen. It didn't work... `awk '$2 >="8:00:00" && $2<="9:00:00"' application.log >awkError`

Comment: @achhainsan  We still have not seen any actual input data, and I can't guess what "didn't work" means -- did a Bird of Paradise fly up your nose ? But obviously 8:00:00 will match both 08:00:00 and 18:00:00, so maybe that's it.

Comment: I've updated how the logs look like. Take a look.

Comment: Then the last approach should work for your input.

Comment: If the log covers several days (or wraps over midnight), it would be advisable to include the date in the checks to avoid time (apparently) running backwards.

Comment: I'm unable to understand what kind of script is this(the last one).

Comment: the last isn't working.

Comment: @achhainsan, that's all code for `sh`-like shells which you can put in a script or run at your prompt. They invoke either `awk` or `perl` to interpret the awk/perl code passed as argument. For all of the them, the input may be passed on stdin or in a filepath argument.

Comment: hey...how do I get logs of only 2023-09-12 only and not 2023-09-13? Everything is in same log

Answer (score 8):

The pattern `/10:..:/` matches the digits 10, two separators of `:`, and any two characters between them. So it will match a time (anywhere within the input line) like `10:35:22`. But it would also match a line containing `This10:ZZ:Camels`, so it is not a very good test.

A better pattern might be `/10:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/`, which checks that the minutes and seconds are in the range 00-59. But it could also be helpful to check the times are in a particular field, or have whitespace around then, or are  (inclusively)near the start of the record.  You might post a few sample input lines so we can better tell what is required.

Having two patterns separated by a comma "switches on" the match when the first pattern is detected, and "switches off" the match when the second pattern is detected. It will match all lines between those events (inclusively), even if they do not contain a date at all.

This is very different to the single pattern `/1[0-2]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/`, which would match only individual lines between 10:00:00 and 12:59:59, in whatever order they happened to be.

Comment: what's with [0-5] [0-9] in MM column and SS column?

Comment: @achhainsan  It matches two consecutive characters which make up the range 00 to 59, just like my answer says. So it checks that the MM and SS parts are actually numeric, and in the correct range for those fields. It is wise to minimise false matches (like `10:ZZ:` in my answer), especially as we have not seen any of your actual data. In particular, log records tend to be effusive and contain strings that come from user data input which can contain almost anything.

Comment: *But it would also match a line containing `This10:ZZ:Camels`, so it is not a very good test.*  Which is just another reason to always make the first field of any log file an ISO8601-formatted date/time.

Comment: @AndrewHenle  Completely agree. But a lot of legacy applications just use their `date` local default, and then start scraping logs when the systems get buggy. I even found one that left the date off completely -- we counted backwards to find time transitions over 00:00:00, and devoutly hoped there were no hidden days.

Comment: I've updated how the logs look like. Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

the awk pattern:

```
/regA/,/regB/
```

will be true from the first line matching regA, until the first line matching regB.
And as usual, when something matches an expression: if there are no `{ actions }` after the expression to precise what actions to perform when it matches, the default action is : print the line where the expression is true.

Now they chose:

```
/10:..:/, /13:..:/
```

to be a (little) bit more sure that you match  10:mm:ss and not hh:10:ss.
(They do this by assuming that any citation of time will be :  hh:mm:ss, and that there are no ':' before the hour ... this is not always true, depending on the date format used. And as said in the comments, it could also match other things as well.

If you know that the beginning of lines is always:

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+hh:mm 
# For exemple:
# 2023-07-17T11:14:02+02:00 , which is following internationnal recommendations
# of displaying date and time (and timezone)
```

You could match more closely with:

```
/^2023-07-17T10:/,/^2023-07-17T13:/
```

and ensure you match only from the beginning (^) of the line and not wherever those things could appear on the line.

Comment: I've updated how the logs look like. Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution that selects logs between two time stamps in a log file. This script assumes that the log file has space-separated columns, and the second column contains the time stamp in the format `HH:MM:SS`. *Might not be the most elegant but at least it is legible.*

```shell
awk -F" " '$2 >= "09:00:00" && $2 <= "12:00:00"' server.log
```

- `-F" "` sets the field separator to a space character.
- `$2` refers to the second field in each line of the input file (fields are separated by spaces in this case).
- `>= "09:00:00"` checks if the value of the second field is greater than or equal to "09:00:00".
- `&&` a logical operator that combines conditions. It means "and"
- `$2 <= "12:00:00"` checks if the value of the second field is less than or equal to "12:00:00".
- `sever.log` is your input file

### Solution Verification

For a `server.log` that looks something like this:

```
2023-07-18 08:55:32 - Log entry 1
2023-07-18 09:10:15 - Log entry 2
2023-07-18 10:30:47 - Log entry 3
2023-07-18 11:45:02 - Log entry 4
2023-07-18 12:05:21 - Log entry 5
2023-07-18 13:20:33 - Log entry 6
```

Output:

```shellsession
[get@me test]$ awk -F" " '$2 >= "09:00:00" && $2 <= "12:00:00"' server.log
2023-07-18 09:10:15 - Log entry 2
2023-07-18 10:30:47 - Log entry 3
2023-07-18 11:45:02 - Log entry 4
```

Comment: It's not known that time will start from 9:00:00 and it's not given that there will be time like 12:00:00. so how'd the regex change?

Comment: sorry I'm quite puzzled by your followup question. The solution above shows logs that are timestamped between 09:00:00 and up to and including 12:00:00. These variables are time in 24 hr format as you described in your question - you adjust these two bounds depending on what time range interests you. What exactly do you mean by `it's not known that time will start from 9:00:00 and it's not given that there will be time like 12:00:00.`

Comment: I've updated how the logs look like. Take a look.